# HUD Section 8 100% Median Income Data

Tags: data-request, income

HUD provide data for the median income at the 30%, 50% 80% percentile of median income, by FIPS Code for household sizes 1 thru 8.

See
http://www.huduser.org/portal/datasets/il/il14/index.html

Some sample data

STATE:ARIZONA ---------------------------I N C O M E L I M I T S----------------------------
PROGRAM 1 PERSON 2 PERSON 3 PERSON 4 PERSON 5 PERSON 6 PERSON 7 PERSON 8 PERSON
Flagstaff, AZ MSA
FY 2014 MFI: 57900 EXTR LOW INCOME 12500 15730 19790 23850 27910 31970 36030 39300
VERY LOW INCOME 20850 23800 26800 29750 32150 34550 36900 39300
LOW-INCOME 33350 38100 42850 47600 51450 55250 59050 62850

I'm looking for data or an 'approved' method to get the 100% median income for household sizes 1 thru for each FIPS code.

Answer (score 5):

As Andrew has suggested, you could just use ACS data [here](http://factfinder2.census.gov/bkmk/table/1.0/en/ACS/12_5YR/B19019/0100000US.05000.004). Make sure to download as a .csv to get the FIPS State-County codes.

Answer (score 4):

You won't find 100% median income in the tables because HUD qualification is limited to low and very low income families and individuals.

http://portal.hud.gov/hudportal/HUD?src=/topics/rental_assistance/phprog

The income data comes from the US Census and American Community Survey.

You can calculate it yourself. Just do 2X the 50% value. Note that HUD rounds the results to the nearest $250 increment.